# How do I open a Strapi project after closing it?

Tags: strapi

How do I open a Strapi project after closing it?

I created a project in Strapi, but after I closed it, I don't know how to open it again.

Answer (score 0):

The command for starting up a strapi project is :

**using npm:**
`npm run develop`

**using yarn:**
`yarn develop`

Once the server is started you can access it on `http://localhost:1337/`

**P.S**: Make sure you run `npm install` or `yarn install` to install the project dependencies before running the above commands.